# Azure App Service Suddenly SSL Certificate is invalid

Tags: azure, ssl

There is a website hosted as an azure app service that has been in production for about a month.  The dns and ssl cert are through network solutions.  SSL has been working fine for a month, today browsers are returning an NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID Your connection is not private.  If I run the digicert diagnostic tool on the certificate it returns information about azure:

```
Common Name = *.azurewebsites.net
Subject Alternative Names = *.azurewebsites.net, *.scm.azurewebsites.net, *.azure-mobile.net, *.scm.azure-mobile.net
```

How can this be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the http bindings from SNI to IP Based and that seems to have resolved it.